# Oracle Forms - LOV FRM-41830 Listo of values contains no entries

Tags: oracle11g, oracleforms

Oracle Forms 10g 
oracle XE 11g database

I created a simple form  to pop up the LOV if the button pressed .
PFB the steps I followed

created a button --> Trigger( when_button_pressed )-> PL/SQL Editor

`declare
    success boolean;
begin
    success := show_lov('COURSE_LOV');
end;`

in Course_lov --> Set the Return value --> Automatic Display -> YES, 
 the sql code associated with COURSE_LOV is below

```
SELECT ALL FORMCOURSE.COURSE_ID, FORMCOURSE.COURSE_NAME, FORMCOURSE.COURSE_VENUE FROM FORMCOURSE
```

The above query , when i run separately, returns values. but

when I clicked the button (while running the form) It gives the below error

```
FRM-41830 List of values contains no entries
```

what could be the issue ? kindly help .

Comment: Pls let me know , if you need any more inputs

Comment: Are you using the same user in both cases?

Comment: @pablomatico - Sorry My Blunder.. please see the answer I posted. thanks for your reply ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was

My Blunder ...

after inserting the data in the formcourse table. I did not COMMIT :( . the query was returning the rows in TOAD but did not return values in forms LOV. once I commit , now its showing in the LOV.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this code in the **Key-listval trigger**:

```
declare
    success boolean;
begin
    success := show_lov('COURSE_LOV');
    execute_query;
end;
```